# Extending RTF in XPM

Tags: gui-extensions, rtf

I want to extend RTF options. I am able to do it in CMS but I am not able to do the same in XPM. In my custom editor'c config, I have both CME as well as SiteEdit as my target and I have tried changing view and control name but it is not picking up new option for XPM.
Which view and control needs to be applied for the same. Do let me know if I need to provide more information regarding the same.
I have attached two images one with cms config entries and other siteedit.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you share your complete config?

Comment: have added the same in two parts above.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it is not picking up new option for XPM" - do you simply mean the option you expect isn't showing... in which case can you confirm if your extension code is being integrated into the output JS. If the code is, can you trigger it via the console app? If you can trigger from the console app does it get the JS you expect... are there conditions in the isAvailable and/or isEnabled that may preclude it from showing/enabling/being used?

Comment: I want to extend Format Page area in XPM. Extension is working fine in CME. I guess this means my JS code is correct but real problem lies in my Editor configuration. I have tried to inspect existing Format Page area and have edited my configurations accordingly but it doesnot work

Answer (score 3):

Extension you are referring was for UI-2012. so may be some IDs would have been changed in XPM 2013

Check for pageid, groupid, and following via inspecting.

```
 <ext:view name="EditorView">
              <ext:control id="MainToolbar"/>
            </ext:view>
```

try giving unique assign id.

refer this link for other debugging purpose [Setting up a SDL Tridion 2011 GUI extension in 8 steps](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/GUIextensionIn8steps.aspx)