# Disabling text field properties popup in experience manager

Tags: experience-manager, 2013-sp1

I am sure there is a button or a setting somewhere to do this but can't see where. Basically just want to disable the pop up below when in experience manager.

[image: Pop-up]

The pop-up appears when editing a rich text area in Tridion. However we find that it doesn't have enough options on it and so is more of a hindrance than a help and we would prefer our users to just use the options on the ribbon.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Why would you take away the option to do the most common tasks quickly? Just like some people prefer to use keyboard shortcuts, some use the context menu, and some the toolbar buttons -- more options for doing the same thing is usually a good thing!

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for the comment. Not really as we have locked down most of the options that appear in the box and so it is confusing to our content providers. Do you know if it is possible to disable and if so how? Thanks again, Matt

Comment: I don't know of any way to do that, no. Maybe you could suppress it with a GUI extension, but I don't know how off the top of my head.

Comment: I see the XPM rich text popup as similar to Word's contextual shortcuts, but Word's version only appears when highlighting or right-clicking on text. In Experience Manager it always shows up when selecting rich text. It's close-able, can be dragged around, and seems to open outside the editable text (so it can be mostly ignored), but it's only contextual to a field rather than a selection.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. Think it will just have to be a training issue that if they don't like it they can just close it. Thanks again for taking the time to write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a setting anywhere for you to enable / disable this functionality.

It's possible to write GUI extensions so you should be able to hook into the functionality to disable it.

There's a couple of questions that are worth reading to help you implement this:

[Extending RTF in XPM](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5763/extending-rtf-in-xpm)

[How to override XPM Cancel Button?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11217/how-to-override-xpm-cancel-button)

Comment: Thanks for the answer think we are just going to go down the route of it being a training issue and they can close it.